# Integrating facebook login/logout to http://localhost/

Tags: php, facebook

I made a facebook login/logout testing code for my website and it works fine but when I integrated it to my website the only thing that works is login and I cant make it logout to my website. what seems to be the problem.

in my index.php I have this code:

```
     `<div class="logout" >
         <?php if(!$user){?>                
                <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl?>">login</a><?php 
              }else{?> 
                <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl?>">logout</a>
               <?php }?>
        </div>`
```

But when I try to separate :

```
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl?>">login</a>
```

and

```
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl?>">logout</a>
```

to another page like :
     index.php for :`<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl?>">login</a>`
and home.php for: ">logout
I cant make it work and of course just incase you'll ask about
the sdk I have this 
`<?php
    include_once "fbaccess.php";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('DirectoryForYour/'.'fbaccess.php');

<div class="logout">
<?php if(!$user): ?>                
                <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">login</a>
<?php else: ?> 
                <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">logout</a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But what I wanted to achieved is to separate the location of  ' <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">login</a>' to another page

Comment: ok, it's callback function in Javascript Do the redirect yourself , add this to JavaScript, somewhere after FB.init():

<script>
  FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function() {window.location = '/home.php'});
</script>
or in function php: function LogoutFacebook() {    
FB.logout(function (response) {
    window.location = "/home.php"; //callback
});   }

Comment: I am truthfully appreciating your help Mr.Gregory. I would like to ask a favor. can you give me a sample code of facebook-php-sdk v4.0.0 that can login and logout and when it is login it will return the id and the name of the fb user. please. I really need your help.
-Best Regards